# how to fade out one div and fade in another div at same time using Jquery

Tags: jquery, fadein, setinterval, jquery-hover

I have three divs,
`newDivforWraping1,#newDivforWraping5,#newDivforWraping9`.

I want to fadeIn `newDivforWraping1` div and fade out `#newDivforWraping5,#newDivforWraping9`

and after that fade out 
`newDivforWraping1,#newDivforWraping9`
and fadein #newDivforWraping5
`and finally fadeIn`#newDivforWraping9`

and fadeOut `#newDivforWraping1,#newDivforWraping9`.

At any point on screen, I have only div seen.

that is

```
<div1>--fade In
<div2>--fade Out
<div3>--fade Out

<div2>--fade In
<div3>--fade Out
<div1>--fade Out

<div3>--fade In
<div1>-fade Out
<div2> -- fade Out
```

kindly notice that whatever div appears on screen, it is on same location on screen. I have set timer using `setInterval` to repeat this process but when user hover mouse over it, I want it to pause (if not possible, then stop). and resume when mouse is not hovering on it.
I have [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/RQNrt/5/) here and you could see my current partially working solution here. Thanks for helping out..

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for some kind of carousel..? There are many to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
(function () {
var i = 1;
var timer=setInterval(function () {
    if(i>3) {i=1};
    runAnimation(i, i, i);
    i++;
},1000); //increase it to 3000 if each fade in runAnimation is up to 1000 on function runAnimation


function runAnimation(a,b,g){
    c = a == 1? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';
    d = b == 2? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';
    h = g == 3? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';

    $("#newDivforWraping1")[c](0); //if a ==1 then $("#newDivforWraping1").fadeIn(0) else $("#newDivforWraping1").fadeOut(0)
    $("#newDivforWraping5")[d](0);
    $("#newDivforWraping9")[h](0);
}

$("#newDivforWraping1,#newDivforWraping5,#newDivforWraping9").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
}, function(){
    timer=setInterval(function () {
    if(i>3) {i=1};
    runAnimation(i, i, i);
    i++;
},1000);
});    

})();
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/RQNrt/32/

Comment: great! this solution works the right way I wanted. If you could explain how the function runAnimation works, it would be useful for me and others to understand.

Comment: c,d,h is the name of which function "fade" (In/Out) would be use. The problem is just rotational activating these flags a, b or g each time interval cycle. You could up the each fade to 1000 miliseconds, then you should get the timer duration up to 3000 also. If you pleased with the demo, just mark on my answer. Glad to help.

Comment: I have voted you up and marked your answer too. can you comment what this means `$("#newDivforWraping1")[c](0)` ?

Comment: I've just added more comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do both at the same time dont use the fadeIn/fadeOut callback for the second call.
Because HJavascript runs the nex fading FX direct.

```
$("#newDivforWraping1").fadeIn(1000);
$("#newDivforWraping5").fadeOut(1000);
```